# Using logistic regression on groups of candidate SNPs in genetic study

Tags: logistic, multiple-comparisons, genetics

I'm working with a large number of candidate SNPs (about 55) in a smallish sample (n=157), looking at a binary sub-diagnosis of schizophrenia (my dependent variable). Basically I am trying to determine which genotype of which SNPs, if any, are associated with this sub-diagnosis. I am trying to sort out a model which will account for the multiple comparisons problem. I have settled on grouping my SNPs into phenotype (e.g. this group previously associated with symptom x, this group with symptom y), running logistic regression on each group, and using the omnibus test to determine if the group is significantly associated - this would tell me that one or more members of that group are driving the association. I would then correct for the number of groups, which represents the number of tests I have performed.

My question is twofold: first, does this make sense? Second, can anyone help me find precedence: a paper in which something similar was done (doesn't have to be in genetics).

Comment: Are they all biallelic SNPs?

Comment: I must admit I'm not too familiar with the term biallelic, but if I've interpreted it properly, then no. Each participant could be minor or major homozygotic or heterozygotic for each SNP - all SNPs are coded as ordinal variables from 0 to 2, representing the number of minor alleles.

Comment: This is fundamentally flawed; you are grouping by phenotype, and then testing if phenotype is associated with group. Clearly there's a problem.

Comment: @CliffAB I might not have been clear - I'm grouping by one phenotype (in this case, negative symptoms) but testing if that phenotype is associated with a different phenotype.